# check string by iterate

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
str1=input()

for i in str1:
    if i=='a'
         print('word:a')
    else:
         continue
         print('without:a')
```

I input one word. And i want to check  if the word content letter:'a'.
use    `print()` in the end.

The problem is I do not know how to excute the code after `continue`

The result i want like this:

> ex1:
>
> > apple
> >
> > word:a
>
> ex2:
>
> > home
> >
> > without:a

Comment: You can't run code in a loop after a continue... That's kinda the point of continue statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are required to use a for loop rather than just check `'a' in str1`, use a for-else

```
str1=input()

for i in str1:
    if i=='a'
        print('word:a')
        break
else:
    print('without:a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'a' in input():
    print('word:a')
else:
    print('without:a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("word:a" if 'a' in input() else "without a")
```